# Override dhcpcd.conf from SD card

Tags: sd-card, dhcp, static-ip

I attempted to set up a static ip in `dhcpcd.conf`, but it appears I made a mistake somewhere, as the Pi does not appear on the network anymore. I have no monitors or keyboards, and ssh was my only method of accessing it. Is there any way to override the file and get it connected again through the sd card?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the SD card out of the pi and put it in whatever other device you have

Edit the `cmdline.txt` file in the boot partition, it'll look something like

```
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=xxxxxxxx-02 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet
```

add to the end of that line

```
systemd.run=/boot/firstrun.sh systemd.run_success_action=reboot systemd.unit=kernel-command-line.target
```

Create a file in the boot partition called `firstrun.sh` with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
set +e
cat > /etc/dhcpcd.conf <<'DHCPCDEOF'
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
# Some non-RFC compliant DHCP servers do not reply with this set.
# In this case, comment out duid and enable clientid above.
#duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Respect the network MTU. This is applied to DHCP routes.
option interface_mtu

# Most distributions have NTP support.
#option ntp_servers

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate SLAAC address using the Hardware Address of the interface
#slaac hwaddr
# OR generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses based from the DUID
slaac private

# Example static IP configuration:
#interface eth0
#static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24
#static ip6_address=fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::ff/64
#static routers=192.168.0.1
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::1

# It is possible to fall back to a static IP if DHCP fails:
# define static profile
#profile static_eth0
#static ip_address=192.168.1.23/24
#static routers=192.168.1.1
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1

# fallback to static profile on eth0
#interface eth0
#fallback static_eth0
DHCPCDEOF
rm -f /boot/firstrun.sh
sed -i 's| systemd.run.*||g' /boot/cmdline.txt
exit 0
```

Stick the card back in the pi and boot

Note: this will set the content of `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` to the default state, exactly as it was when you first flashed the OS

Answer (score 0):

You have made 2 fundamental errors; changing a system file without backup and setting a static IP address.

There are many ways to fix this;

The easiest is to mount the SD Card on a Linux computer.

You can connect to another computer with an Ethernet cable and `ssh` using `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local`

Rebooting to a root shell can repair most problems on the Pi, but needs keyboard & screen or serial console.

1. Append `init=/bin/sh` at the end of `cmdline.txt` and reboot.
2. After booting you will be at the prompt in a root shell.
3. Your root file system is mounted as readonly now, so remount it as
   read/write `mount -n -o remount,rw /`
4. Fix your problem
5. Remove `init=/bin/sh` and reboot.

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain why setting a static ip is a fundamental error? mDNS isn't working on my network, and a static ip seems like the only solution.

Comment: @pythonian23 There is no NEED to set a Static IP Address. Many new Pi users try and get it wrong.
If you want your Pi to be assigned a **predictable** IP Address you can either reserve one in your router OR **request** the DHCP server to assign one or you can **inform** the DHCP server.
NOTE either assigns an address to the SD Card NOT the Pi.